# Looping Arrays in SAS Macro

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro

I am quite new with writing macros and I have a sas data step that seems to be repetitive. Is it possible to put this code in a sas macro that loops around the array so it is not repetitively written?

```
data vintage;
set data_have;


array amt {4} mob0-mob3;

if dist = 0 then do;
 do i = 1 to 4;
  amt{i} = dollar_value;
 end;
end;

if dist = 1 then do;
 do i = 2 to 4;
  amt{i} = dollar_val;
 end;
end;

if dist = 2 then do;
 do i = 3 to 4;
  amt{i} = dollar_val;
 end;
end;

if dist = 3 then do;
 do i = 4 to 4;
  amt{i} = dollar_val;
 end;
end;

run;
```

I have tried to write the following macro but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
%macro vx (datain, n, var, wo);

data vin;
set &datain;

array amt {4} mob0-mob3;

%let m = %eval(1+i);

%do i=1 %to &n;
 %if dist = i %then %do;
  %do j=2 %to m;
   mob&j = dollar_val;
  %end;
%end;


run;
%mend vx;
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't see where macro plays into this. You can replace your multiple loops with one do loop.  `do i=1+dist to 4;`

Comment: You need show some example input and output data.

Comment: You're combining macro with non-macro in a way that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this isn't something you need the macro language to solve; see Tom's comments.  But I'll answer how to do it in the macro language anyway, since it is possible, and may help your learning.

Think of the macro language as a code-writer: like a junior programmer that you tell what you want SAS to do, and they do it for you. They're not SAS, they're *writing* SAS, and importantly they can't use the details of the dataset themselves: they can only use what's known about the dataset before it's opened (variable *names* are fine, but not the data in the variables) unless they write some code to find out what is in the dataset separately.

What you're doing is writing this a lot:

```
if dist = 0 then do;
 do i = 1 to 4;
  amt{i} = dollar_value;
 end;
end;
```

But with `0` and `1` varying.  Right?  So let's make them macro variables (rather, one macro variable).

```
if dist = &mv. then do;
 do i = &mv.+1 to 4;
  amt{i} = dollar_value;
 end;
end;
```

Notice I don't use `&i.` here, because that would be confusing.  Instead I'll use something different, `&mv.`.

Then, we need to make sure the `if` and `do` here are the right kinds.  `%do` says "write this code many times".  `do` on the other hand is for normal SAS do loops, and same in both cases for `%if`.

So here, we want to write this block of code many times, so `%do` the whole block; but inside the block, when we want to say `if dist=...` that is regular if (it's looking at the data value), and when we want to say `do i = ... to 4` it is again regular do (it's regular SAS do loop, again dependent on data).

So here we go:

```
%macro vx (datain, n, var, wo);

data vin;
  set &datain;
  array mob[&n.]; *do not have to list them, it is by default;
  %do mv=1 %to &n;
    if dist = &mv then do;   *not MACRO if but regular if;
     do i = (&mv.+1) to m;  *not MACRO loop but regular loop;
       mob[i] = dollar_val;
     end;
    end;
  %end;
run;
%mend vx;
```

Now again, this is better done without macro.

```
data vin;
  set &datain.;
  array amt[4];
  if dist < 4 then do;
    do i = (dist+1) to 4;
      amt[i] = dollar_value;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

But it's certainly doable either way.

Comment: The second data step needs an array declaration?